# MS SQL 2012 - Are IP's being resolved to hostnames by the SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, sql

When I check the activity monitor on the SQL server, under processes, all the hostnames are resolved to the connecting server's hostname. I'm interested to know if the SQL server is resolving the IP address of each connecting server to its hostname, since that could be causing a delay in processing the response.

Is this what is happening, or is the connecting server providing its hostname in the request?

If the server is in fact resolving IP addresses to hostnames, how can I disable this behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is not your problem.

If you'd like to disable DNS lookups from the SQL server anyway, the quickest way would be to blank out the DNS server entries in your network configuration.

Comment: Well that's the thing...there are no entries in the DNS for these hosts. Somehow, the SQL server is resolving the IP addresses into hostnames all on its own. Unless the hosts are providing their hostname inside their request. Could you please elaborate why this wouldn't cause any delay while it resolves the IP address?